# Change language dropdown on a login page

Tags: forms, language, position, options

Where do you believe is the best place to add a change language dropdown menu on a LOGIN page?

Is it below the form?
[image]

Or is it on the right?[image]

Are there any conducted studies you know of?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For First Layout** : If it is a responsive layout, where the Change Language will shift.

According to me the second layout will work good. Beause its all in center, 
User will concentrate only in center he do not have to search for things here and there. Even Google, Facebook have launguage change, at the bottom of the website.

Comment: Thanks Abhisek. Yes the layout will be responsive :)

Comment: my pleasure....

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to display the dropdown at the bottom of the page because: - changing language is not the primary user task for this page 
- the login form has a super low learning curve, most of the user knows how to fill-in such form even if is not written in his own language 
- as a secondary task is not overloading the user with extra information

In my opinion would be helpful for the user to display a placeholder in the "name" field with an example of the user name. Sometimes I've found login forms that are asking for usernames but then you have to write your email.

I hope it will help you